# Class is not being added in the click event handler

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and I'm having problems with the `.on()` event handler. I don't know why the class `done` is not being added to the new list item that was dynamically added. Any assistance would be appreciated.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/Xarvu/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style>
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
.done{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
}
.green{
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#taskText').keydown(function(evt){
        if(evt.keyCode == 13){
            addTask(this, evt);
        }
    });
    $('#addTask').click(function(evt){
        addTask(document.getElementById('taskText'), evt);
    });
//the problem is the code below//

    $('#tasks li').on("click", function(evt){
        $(this).addClass('done');
    });
});
function addTask(textBox, evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var taskText = textBox.value;
    $("<li>").text(taskText).appendTo('#tasks');
    textBox.value = '';
};
</script>
<body>



<ul id = "tasks">

</ul>
<input type= 'text' id ='taskText'>
<input type = 'submit' id ="addTask" />
<div class = "green"> green text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify [that optional `selector` argument for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to work for elements created after the event binding:

```
$('#tasks').on('click', 'li', function(evt){
    $(this).addClass('done');
});
```

Straight from the API docs:

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.** To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers *after* the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or `document` if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the `head` of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.